# Spring Data JPA - filtering @OneToMany relation separately

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Suppose the following:

```
public class Building {
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String zipCode;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "building", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private final Set<Contract> contracts = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Contract {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
   private Building building;


   @Column(nullable = false)
   private LocalDate activeFrom;
}
```

Using preferably spring-data-jpa repositories, how can I select all buildings with a certain `zipCode`, and then for each building, all contracts with an `activeFrom` earlier than X?

All solutions I can find on the internet seem to focus on filtering the primary object (`Building`), whereas I'd like to use different dynamic criteria for the child (`Contract`) and receive an empty list if none are found. **I explicitly want to receive Buildings with no matching Contracts.**

It is fine if a DTO/projection is used rather than the entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

I am going on the assumption you are looking for a JpaRepository query you could use. You can use "_" to apply queries to fields on embedded objects.

For example something like, findAllByBuilding_ZipCodeAndActiveFromBefore...

Comment: This would filter out `Building`s without a `Contract` that is activeBefore X. I explicitly want them returned with an emptyList in contracts.

Comment: Ok right, sorry I didn't find it clear from the question. I understood it as Contract being primary entity you are wanting returned, hence would be empty if nothing found.

Comment: Similarly, not sure of how this can be done in method format, but may be worth using @Query with Join fetches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to filter by zipCode and activeFrom

```
String FIND_ALL_BUILDINGS_BY_ZIP_CODE_AND_ACTIVE_FORM = "SELECT b FROM Building b" +
        " inner join b.contract as c " +
        " with c.activeFrom > :date " +
        " where b.zipCode = :zipCode";

@Query(FIND_ALL_BUILDINGS_BY_ZIP_CODE_AND_ACTIVE_FORM)
List<Group> findAllBuildingsByZipCodeAndActiveFrom(@Param("zipCode") String zipCode, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

This will give you a bulding that has atleast one contract that activeFrom > date

Also you can try with this query:

```
String FIND_ALL_BUILDINGS_BY_ZIP_CODE_AND_ACTIVE_FORM = "SELECT b FROM Building b" +
        " inner join b.contract as c " +
        " where c.activeFrom > :date " +
        " and b.zipCode = :zipCode";
```

Just make sure that you joined the second table before filtering

Comment: `This will give you a bulding that has atleast one contract that activeFrom > date` I'm afraid that's the problem - I explicitly want `Buildings` with no matching contracts returned too.

Comment: than add more conditions with OR